# Is it possible to use a MongoRepository with not-fixed document structure?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that can contain documents that may have different structure. Ex:

```
mycollection.doc1
{ 
  "bar" : "foo",
  "stuff" : "1"
}

mycollection.doc2
{ 
  "bar" : "foo",
  "bla" : [a complex structure]
}
```

I've tried by creating a generic class GenericDocument:

```
@Document(collection = "mycollection")
public class GenericDocument{
  private String bar; // including getter and setter
}
```

and use it in a MongoRepository:

```
public interface GenericDocumentRepository extends MongoRepository<GenericDocument, String> {}
```

When I try to list the documents:

```
@Autowired
private GenericDocumentRepository repo;
(...)
List<GenericDocument> docList = repo.findAll();
```

*docList* contains my docs but I can only see the common property *bar*.

Is there a way to retrieve the entire documents in Map objects, without manually specifying the properties in *GenericDocument*?

Comment: Closest thing you can do : [JsonAnyGetter JsonAnySetter](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html).

Comment: The other ticket (the one that may be duplicated) is about storing data. Mine is more about retrieving data: I don't know the name of the top-level keys.

Comment: "Schemaless" means the data modeling must be enforced on the application side, not that you should store "random" data. You can't process data in the long term if you haven't a glimpse of what it might be. If you can't have a top level field to store a hashmap with your "unknown" data, Spring Data Mongo might not be the right tool for you.